# How to count and print the number of words in each line in a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to count the total no of words in each line in a file and print them.I tried

```
with codecs.open('v.out','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = len(line.strip(' '))
        print words
```

the input file is:

```
hello 
try it
who knows
it may work
```

the output that I get is:

```
6
7
10
12
```

but what I need is:

```
1 
2 
2
3
```

is there any function that I can use? I have to print the first word of each line in a file, and similarly print the middle word and the last word of the line into separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close. This line:

```
words = len(line.strip(' '))
```

should be:

```
words = len(line.split(' '))
```

[`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes characters from the start and end of the string, [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) breaks the string up into a list of strings.

Comment: thank u, I dint think of it!

Comment: am also able to print into files using ff.write(line.split()[0]).

Answer (score 4):

You are *stripping spaces from the ends*, not splitting the words. You are counting the remaining characters now, not words.

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead:

```
words = len(line.split())
```

No arguments required, or use `None`; it'll strip whitespace from the ends, and split on arbitrary-width whitespace, giving you words:

```
>>> 'it may work'.split()
['it', 'may', 'work']
>>> len('it may work'.split())
3
```